# How to change the character after specific exact character using SED command?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I was writing a bash script to change all the B'10' values to B'12' in files.

So I have a file where B'10' is mentioned many times. And it can also be B'1010101010" with different length. All this has to be B'12121212". I tried to change with SED command which is :

```
sed -i -r "/[B'][10]+/s/10/12/g" filename 

sed -i -r "/[B'][[0-9][0-9]]*[10]+/s/10/12/g" filename
```

I had to specify it twice, for only match B'10' and many B'1010101010..". If I only specified the second command, it was ignoring the single B'10' matches. So, This command is changing the values but it is changing for all the "10" matches it can find. But I need to change only after exactly B and single column near B character.

All the help is appreciated!! Thank you.

Comment: `[B']` looks for `B` or `'` and will match `A'10`. `[10]` diesn't look for `10` but for `1` or `0`. Match `10` with `(10)`.

Comment: Try `sed -i -E ":a; s/(\bB'(12)*)10((10)*')/\112\3/g; t a" file`, see [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/rseydH). It will not change `AB'10101'` values and will not touch `B'101245'` like values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your sed supports labels:

```
sed ':1 s/\(B\x27\(12\)*\)10/\112/; t1' file # or
sed -E ':1 s/(B\x27(12)*)10/\112/; t1' file
```

- `:1` label `1`,
- `(B\x27(12)*)` matches `B'` followed by zero or more `12`s, puts it into capturing group `1`,
- `\1` expands to value kept in capturing group 1,
- `t1` means "if a successful substitution is performed, go back to label `1`".

Comment: Wow, this is working. Thank you so much. One question what does x27 mean? Is it for length of the string? If yes, if I want to change only  B'10', so it will be 
` sed ':1 s/\(B\ (12\)*\)10/\112/; t1' file ` ?

Comment: aaa okay. Got it. Thank you!

Comment: One question. Will this command also change if ex: B'AD10KJ10' -- this kinds of strings?

Comment: Can you please share how I can make it to work for examples like B'AD10KJ10' ? Because I have these kinds of strings too on other files.

Comment: Sure, waiting. Thank you

Comment: `sed ':1 s/\(B\x27[^\x27]*\)10/\112/; t1' file` here it is

Comment: Cool, let me try that now. Thank you so much!! @oguzismail

Comment: Hi @oguzismail. I have one question. I have example X'0D25' and I need to change to X'0D0A'. And I used the command sed ':1 s/\(X\x27[^\x27]*\)25/\10D/; t1' file . 
And it is not changing anything. Also I have tried sed ':1 s/\(X\x27[^\[[0-9][A-Z]]]*\)25/\10D/; t1' , but it didn't help. Do you know how can I resolve this?

Comment: @asel `sed ':1 s/\(X\x27\(OD0A\)*0D\)25/\10A/; t1' file` might work

Comment: @oguzismail No, that was the last question. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @asel ookay then

Answer (score 1):

try it by gnu sed before using -i option;

```
sed -E ":s s/\b(B')((12)*)10(10|\"|')/\1\212\4/ ;ts"  filename
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change all `10`'s after `B'`, start with the last `10` in `1010...10`.
After changing the last, do it again and replace the new last `10`.

```
echo "B'1010101010111213" | sed -r ":a; s/B'((10)*)(10)/B'\112/; ta"
```